# Managing privacy choices with amp-analytic

Tags: amp-html, privacy, amp-analytics

I'm *really* bad at web in general, but it seems I'm to do a study on AMP :x

While I managed to send data in-house using amp-analytics I am also trying to display a "privacy popup" and get the user choices to forward them to our analytic tools.

I've tried actually several things, using amp-state and trying to bind to send data with a binding. Tried to override variables declared in my amp-analytics (which worked in one shot with data-vars-name, but don't **set** any value)

```
  <amp-analytics id="testlytics">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
      "vars": {
        "container_id": "2",
        "page_name" : "amp_homepage",
        "user_id" : "",
        "order_id" : "",
        "privacy" : "",
      },

      "requests": {
        "baseURL": "https://baseurl.com/${container_id}/?privacy=${privacy}",

        "pageTrack": "${baseURL}&page_name=${page_name}&user_id=${user_id}&order_id=${order_id}",

        "eventTrack": "${pageTrack}&scrollY=${scrollTop}&scrollX=${scrollLeft}&height=${availableScreenHeight}&width=${availableScreenWidth}&scrollBoundV=${verticalScrollBoundary}&scrollBoundH=${horizontalScrollBoundary}&eventLabel=${eventlabel}"
      },
      "triggers": {
        "pageview": {
          "on": "visible",
          "request": "pageTrack",
          "vars": {
            "type": "page"
          }
        },
        "clickPings": {
          "selector": ".events",
          "on": "click",
          "request": "eventTrack",
          "vars": {
            "type": "event"
          }
        }
      }
    }
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Among my tests was :

```
  <span id="event-test" class="events" data-vars-container_id="3311">
    Click here to generate an event
  </span>

  <span id="event-test" class="events">
    Click here to generate an event that doesn't override container_id
  </span>
```

Which kinda works for events like button click, but can't be used to set a variable for the entire navigation and more.

I also tried using:

```
<amp-state id="privacy_state">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "tag_list": "12"
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<amp-user-notification 
  id="my-notification"
  layout="nodisplay">
  This is an amp-user-notification. It uses local storage to store the dismissed state.
    <button on="tap:AMP.setState({tag_list: '3'})">Change privacy state</button>
    <button on="tap:my-notification.dismiss">I accept</button>
</amp-user-notification>
```

But I can't seem to be able to use what's inside the amp-state inside my amp-analytics anyway.

Does anyone know the best way to do this? Should I write with my popup in the local storage and then how to read this and send it to my server?

Thank you for helping ! :)

Comment: For now, the best I found is using our own data center to store informations about "opt-in" or "opt-out" and create an api for the amp-user-notification "data-show-if-href". But it would mean selling an additional component for our clients which is not wanted :(

Comment: Still commenting myself :D I also would need to know if there is a way to add "extraUrlParams" on the fly or send only when they're not empty. I can send and modify parameters at will, but I would like to only send those needed, so not the empty ones.